# Do we need mahout and hadoop on same machine?

Tags: java, linux, windows, hadoop, mahout

I am trying to build a recommendation engine using mahout, hadoop and java. It is my first time working with hadoop, I am getting my data sets from a server where hadoop is already installed which is a linux enviroment. My development environment is windows, now do I need to install mahout in my development environment or the server? If I need mahout on my development environment do I also need to install hadoop in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have Hadoop on your machine, Mahout will run in pseudo-distributed mode on the current machine.

Nonetheless, Windows and Hadoop don't really like each other, and depending on your Mahout version (more specifically the Hadoop dependency it has), you will most likely run into this issue ([link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/mahout-user/201207.mbox/%3C501795E6.3010903@fredhopper.com%3E)). The issue is present from Hadoop 0.20.204 onwards (although I must admit that I don't know if it has been fixed on the latest version of Hadoop)